# Redmine API get time entries report

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

Redmine API can serve time entries in JSON.

```
$ curl -X GET \
  'https://my_redmine/time_entries.json' \
  -H 'X-Redmine-API-Key: my_api_key'

{"time_entries":[{"id":14212,"project":{"id":73,"name":"Project 1"},"issue":{"id":5488},"user":{"id":5,"name":"John SMITH"},"activity":{"id":8,"name":"Grouillot"},"hours":8.0,"comments":"dsgsdsdh","spent_on":"2020-03-09","created_on":"2020-01-07T14:03:58Z","updated_on":"2020-01-07T14:33:52Z", ...
```

Now I need to get them aggregated and I'd rather use the built in **report** aggregation feature than doing it myself after having fetched all the required time entries.

Let's say we have these time entries

```
+------+----------+-------+------------+
| user | issue_id | hours | spent_on   |
+------+----------+-------+------------+
|    1 |       42 |     4 | 2020-01-01 |
|    1 |       43 |     4 | 2020-01-01 |
|    2 |       42 |     8 | 2020-01-01 |
+------+----------+-------+------------+
```

If I want them to be aggregated by user, **here is what need** to get

```
+------+-------+------------+
| user | hours | spent_on   |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 |     8 | 2020-01-01 |
|    2 |     8 | 2020-01-01 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to do that in the [current REST API](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_TimeEntries)

But since a report can be generated by CSV with this kind of query

```
https://my_redmine/time_entries/report.csv?columns=day&criteria%5B%5D=user
```

I naively though we could use it like

```
$ curl -X GET \
  'https://my_redmine/time_entries/report.json?columns=day&criteria%5B%5D=user' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-Redmine-API-Key: my_api_key'
```

But no luck, it returns a redirection to an HTML login form.
Even fetching the CSV with the API key or a basic auth doesn't seem possible.

Does anyone would have any idea about **getting the time entries aggregated** with a REST HTTP query ?